# How to remove time from date react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
function ListStudents() {
  const [opened, setOpened] = useState(false);
  const [openeed, setOpeneed] = useState(false);


  const [sms, setSms] = useState([]);

  //delete data function
  const deleteSms = async id => {
    try {
      const deleteSms = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/sms/student/${id}`, {
        method: "DELETE",
        headers: {
          jwt_token: localStorage.token
        }
      });

      setSms(sms.filter(student => student.student_id !== id));

    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  }

  const getSms = async() => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/sms/student");

      const jsonData = await response.json();

      setSms(jsonData);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getSms()
  }, []);



  return ( <
      Fragment >

      <
      Container mt = {
        40
      } >
      <
      br / >

      <
      Group position = "center" >

      <
      Button variant = "light"
      color = "cyan"
      onClick = {
        () => setOpeneed(true)
      } >

      <
      IconPlus size = {
        18
      }
      pd = "xl" / >
      &
      nbsp; Add Student <
      /Button> < /
      Group >

      <
      Modal centered size = "xl"
      opened = {
        openeed
      }
      onClose = {
        () => setOpeneed(false)
      } >
      <
      Text align = "center" > Add Student < /Text> <
      AddStudent / >
      <
      /Modal>

      <
      br / >
      <
      br / >

      <
      Table height = {
        300
      }
      verticalSpacing = "lg"
      horizontalSpacing = "xl"
      striped highlightOnHover >
      <
      thead >
      <
      tr >
      <
      th > First Name < /th> <
      th > Last Name < /th> <
      th > Phone No < /th> <
      th > Email < /th> <
      th > Class Room < /th> <
      th > Section < /th> <
      th > Date of Registration < /th> < /
      tr > <
      /thead> <
      tbody > {
        sms.map(student => ( <
            tr key = {
              student.student_id
            } >
            <
            td > {
              student.first_name
            } < /td> <
            td > {
              student.last_name
            } < /td> <
            td > {
              student.phone_no
            } < /td> <
            td > {
              student.email
            } < /td> <
            td > {
              student.class_room
            } < /td> <
            td > {
              student.section
            } < /td> <
            td > {
              student.date
            } < /td>
```

What is the best way to remove time from the student.date function and display only the date in my application?

Comment: what is the current value of `student.date` ?

Comment: Something like `Date.parse(student.date).toLocaleDateString()` should do the trick.

Comment: what do you mean delete? just do not render that if it is not necessary